# Find the tangent line to a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

Find the tangent line to the curve $x^2y - y^2 + x = 11$ at the point $(3,1)$

I tried to solve it using parametric equations

\begin{cases}
y = t \\[4px]
x = -\dfrac{1}{2t} + \dfrac{\sqrt{1+4t^3 + 44t}}{2t}
\end{cases}

and the derivative of $x(t)$, $y(t)$, $t= 1$ gives the direction vector $( 5/7 , 1 )$
so the line that passes through $(3,1)$

l: $(3,1) + s(5/7 , 1) $

Is it correct? Because using desmos the line doesn't seem to be tangent to the curve.

Comment: You have computed the derivative wrongly.

Comment: That's not really using parametric equations to their full advantage.  You've solved for x, and then used y=t to fake using parametric equations.  You could also solve for y and then proceed as you normally would for y=f(x).  But it would be better to approach this as an implicit or parametric equation, and use the methods there.  That saves you from having to solve a quadratic, and from having to differentiate a fraction involving a square root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$ has equation
$$
(x-x_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+
(y-y_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0
$$
where the partial derivatives are computed at $(x_0,y_0)$ and $f(x,y)=x^2y-y^2+x-11$.

Since
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&=2xy+1 \\[6px]
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&=x^2-2y
\end{align}
the tangent line has equation
$$
7(x-3)+7(y-1)=0
$$
that is, $x+y-4=0$.

[image]

---

You have made some error in computing the derivative of $x(t)$.

Solving the equation $x^2t+x-t^2-11=0$ with respect to $x$ yields
$$
x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+44t+4t^3}}{2t}
$$
If $t=1$, we get
$$
x=\frac{-1\pm7}{2}
$$
so we need to take the branch with $+$.

The derivative of $x(t)$ is
$$
x'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\dfrac{22+6t^2}{\sqrt{1+44t+4t^3}}-(\sqrt{1+44t+4t^3}-1)}{t^2}
$$
For $t=1$ we get
$$
x'(1)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\dfrac{28}{7}-(7-1)}{1}=-1
$$

Comment: Math and $\mathrm\LaTeX$... perfect combo!! $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: thank you i have found the error but i love this way more its awesome glad to be half right

Comment: egreg, how do you derive your first equation for a tangent line? I searched everywhere but all i found was parametric equations of the tangent line.

Comment: @RoyalBeatlemaniac https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve#Tangent_at_a_point

Comment: egreg, thank you for replying but how is this derived?

Comment: I know this seems elementary but I have been searching for one and a half hours...

Comment: @RoyalBeatlemaniac The total differential…

Comment: Thank you egreg, I'll spend some more time searching and understanding.

Comment: @RoyalBeatlemaniac The total differential is a linear map that describes the tangent space at the point. Exactly what we need here, isn't it? You want to find the line that best approximates the curve at the given point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126267/discussion-between-royal-beatlemaniac-and-egreg).

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have that

$$x^2y-y^2+x=11\implies 2xydx+x^2dy-2ydy+dx=0\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy+1}{2y-x^2}$$

then at $(3,1)$ the slope is $-1$.